# Passing type information to function in Scala

Tags: function, scala, types

I have code that does some common operation on json objects, namely extract. So what I would like to create generic function that takes type parameter which class to expect, code looks like as follows:

```
def getMessageType[T](json: JValue): Either[GenericError,T] = {
  try {
    Right(json.extract[T])
  } catch {
    case e: MappingException => jsonToError(json)
  }
}
```

The issue is how to pass T information to that function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at [the definition of extract](https://github.com/lift/lift/blob/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/json/Extraction.scala): you will see that it takes a
`Manifest` implicitly:

```
def extract[A](json: JValue)
    (implicit formats: Formats, mf: Manifest[A]): A
```

This gets around JVM type erasure by taking the "type" in as a value. For your
case, I think you should do the same thing:

```
def getMessageType[T](json: JValue)
    (implicit f: Formats, mf: Manifest[T]): T =
{
    json.extract[T]
}
```

This:

1. Gives your method implicit parameters, which must be fulfilled by the caller.
2. Creates (those same) implicit parameters to pass them on to `extract`.